# Simulation using a Queue

Tags: python, python-2.7, queue, simulation, exponential-distribution

I am trying to simulate the following simple scenario using a queue:

"Students come to a professor's office to receive help on a homework assignment every 10 minutes exponentially distributed. The time to help a student is exponentially distributed with a mean of 7 minutes. What are the expected number of students waiting to be helped and the average waiting time before being helped? For what percentage of time is it expected there will be more than two students at the professor's office?"

I started by making the following queue but I'm struggling how to create a global time clock and how to integrate students leaving the queue.

```
import random as rd

class Queue(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.officeHasStudent = False
        self.totalTime = 0
        self.numStudentsInLine = 0
    def studentArrives(self, time):
        self.totalTime += time
        if self.officeHasStudent == False:
            self.officeHasStudent = True
        else:
            self.numStudentsInLine += 1
    def __str__(self):
        temp = ''
        temp += 'Time Elapsed: ' + str(self.totalTime) + ' min\n'
        temp += 'number of students in line: ' + str(self.numStudentsInLine)
        return temp

Q = Queue()

for i in range(5):
    Q.studentArrives(rd.expovariate(1/10.0))

print(Q)
```

Comment: Is your focus on making a functional simulation, or on building a queue object?  If it's the former, you can create a queue quite simply using the recurrence `arrival_time = arrival_time + expovariate(arrival_rate)`, `begin_service = max(end_service, arrival_time)`, and `end_service = begin_service + expovariate(service_rate)`.  Initialize `arrival_time` and `end_service` to 0, embed the three state updates in a loop, and you have yourself an M/M/1 queueing model!

Comment: @pjs my focus is on making a functional simulation using a queue.

Comment: Check out this [discrete-event simulation engine](https://github.com/PaulSanchez/SimpleKit-Python/).  An M/M/k implementation is provided as a demo model.  If you insist on using an actual `Queue` object, create one in the `__init__` method, push students onto it in the `arrival` event method, and pop them off in the `beginService` event method.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `Queue` must also be aware of when the last student entered the office and when (s)he is to leave besides the number of students in the row and when the next is to come. Furthermore, I would not think of 'global time' as a primary quantity, instead, my algorithm would be something like the following.

You always have to calculate what happens next:

1. New student to the end of the queue? Then calculate when the next student (after him/her) will arrive to the queue.
2. Student emitted from the office? Then check: is there still a student waiting in the queue?

   - if yes: calculate when (s)he leaves the office.
   - if no: calculate when the next student arrives, when (s)he is automatically admitted to the office, so calculate also when (s)he leaves the office and when the next student arrives.
3. Go back to see what happens next.

And as I said, 'global time' is then just a derived quantity that is always easy to calculate (update) for each action.

Comment: That makes sense but I do not know how to implement that into the queue and then calculate those statistics.